# Laravel mails not sending from Cron Job

Tags: laravel, email, cron

I am sending mails from my App and there are no problems when sending them from an user request.

But from a Cron Job the mails are not sending.

I am listening to `MessageSent` and `MessageSending` events and logging them. What is interesting is that mail sent from cron jobs appear in the logs.

**Cron Job code**

```php
class UserPracticeLessonsCheckJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
        $time_for_payment = Carbon::now()
            ->subMinutes(config('payment.minutes_for_payment'));

        UserPaymentCheck::where('created_at', '<', $time_for_payment)
            ->with('user')->get()
            ->each(function ($userPaymentCheck) use ($time_for_payment) {
                $user = $userPaymentCheck->user;

                if ($user->hasUnpaidPracticeLessons()) {
                    $user->removeUnpaidPracticeLessons();
                    // Send mails to user with cancelled lessons
                    $user->sendPracticeLessonsCancellationMail();
                }

                $userPaymentCheck->delete();
            });
    }
}
```

User trait with `sendPracticeLessonsCancellationMail` function:

```php
trait SendPracticeLessonsCancellationMail
{
    public function sendPracticeLessonsCancellationMail()
    {
        \Mail::to($this)->send(new PracticeLessonsCancellationMail($this));
    }
}
```

And the Mailable class:

```php
class PracticeLessonsCancellationMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->markdown('emails.practice.practice-schedule-cancellation')
            ->subject(app_name() . ': ' . __('students.backend.emails.practice.practice_schedule_cancellation'))
            ->attachData($this->user->practice_schedule_pdf->stream(), $this->user->full_name . ' - planificare.pdf', [
                'mime' => 'application/pdf',
            ]);
    }
}
```

Is this a configuration issue or a bug in Laravel?

Comment: Can you please include the cron function. You are using the Mail Queue?

Comment: @JijinP I don't use the Mail Queue.

Comment: Does the mail send if you call `$user->sendPracticeLessonsCancellationMail();` outside of the queued job?

Comment: Yes. The mail is sent if I call it from a Controller.

Comment: maybe your config is different somehow when running as cron. Log the output of `config('mail')` inside the `function sendPracticeLessonsCancellationMail()` and compare the output when the mail is send and when se mail is not send.

Comment: @PKeidel Config is same in both cases.

Comment: does the corn job if statement work just without sending mail ? does it removeUnpaidPracticeLessons ?

Comment: Yes. Also the mails sent from cron jobs appear in the logs

Comment: what is your value for `config('mail.driver')`?

Comment: Which version of laravel / php are you running, also what queue connection are you using for your job?

Comment: Value of `config('mail.driver')` is `smtp`.

Comment: Laravel`5.6.39`. PHP `7.1.14`. I use `sync` connection.

Comment: if it is `smtp`, in which logfile can you see that the mail is being send?

Comment: I am listening to `MessageSent` and `MessageSending` events and logging them. Mails sent from cron jobs also appears in log files.

Comment: What happens if you use the 'log' driver for emails? Do they appear in the laravel logs?

Comment: Yes. But I see a little difference between mails sent from cron jobs and mails send from controllers. Mails sent from cron jobs have Message ID like this `cd06d32ece145874799ac4fdb057fa6d@swift.generated`. But Message ID for mails sent from controllers ends with `@my-domain.com`.

Comment: If $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is empty it defaults to @swift.generated. This should be OK...

Comment: Could please you add a log dump for both cases where you `\Mail()->send()` from a controller and the job. This is a unexpected behavior from Laravel that might be cause by some service providers not being loaded when using jobs

Comment: Maybe the message id is the problem, the server denies the request to prevent spoofing?

Comment: @blinkofaneye Is it possible to customize message id?

Comment: I don't really now how it works but if it relies on $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] as mentionned by @shock_gone_wild, then try to set $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] to your domain.

Comment: Simple use php artisan tinker to see what happen on the server side if that works cron will work.

Comment: @blinkofaneye Setting `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to my domain fixed the problem! Can you please add an answer to this question with this fix? I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] to your domain.

Comment: how to set this ?